# ReactJS Toggling between states of array [hooks]

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, react-hooks, use-state

Hy everyone, 
Can you help me please with the problem I have?

So, I have a checkbox and an array of objs fetched from an API request:

```
const ownRequest= [
{status: "pending", type: "aaa"},
{status: "pending", type: "bbb"},
{status: "pending", type: "bbb"},
{status: "pending", type: "aaa"},
{status: "pending", type: "aaa"}
]


export const Types= () => {
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(true);
  const [ownRequest, setOwnRequest] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let ignore = false;

    async function fetchData() {
      const result = await fetchTimeoffRequests();
      if (!ignore) {
        setOwnRequest(result);
      }
    }

    fetchData();
    return () => {
      ignore = true;
    };
  }, []);

  const req = checked ? ownRequest: ownRequest.filter(i=>i.type==="aaa")
  setOwnRequest(req);

  const handleCheck = (event) => {
    setChecked(!checked);
  }
}
return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
     <Checkbox onChange={(e) => handleCheck(e)} checked={checked} />
    </div>
}
```

I would like to display the items like this:
**if is checked show me all items, if not only the items with type:"aaa"**, and also to have the posibility to come back to original state (like a toggle)

I did something, but I can't figure it out how to handle it further

Comment: Could you post the full code? Calling setOwnRequest() within it self will cause an infinite loop. You can just return state or newState.

Comment: i updated my question and also made another try. still can't handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might be over complicating it:

```
const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(false);
const req = [
    {status: "pending", type: "aaa"},
    {status: "pending", type: "bbb"},
    {status: "pending", type: "bbb"},
    {status: "pending", type: "aaa"},
    {status: "pending", type: "aaa"}
]

//Simple filter depending on the checked state with a ternary if
const ownRequest= checked ? req : req.filter(i=>i.type==="aaa")

const handleCheck = (event) => {
     setChecked(!checked);
}

<Checkbox onChange={(e) => handleCheck(e)} checked={checked} />
```

As of the updated question:

The infinite loop comes from `setOwnRequest(req);`. It is because the `setOwnRequest()` causes a re render every time it changes.

Comment: Thanks for solution, but I forgot to mention that **req** are coming from an Api request, and I'm using useEffect, and that's why I'm using const [ownRequest, setOwnRequest] = useState([]);
With your solution is giving me infinite loop.

Comment: Yes. Updated again. Thank you

Comment: The infinite loop comes from `setOwnRequest(req);`. It is because the setOwnRequest() causes a re render every time it changes.

Why do you want to set back the filtered value into it?

You can use req in return() to display the requests.

Comment: That was the problem! Thank you ! Unfortunately I can'y give you a star, but you deserve it!

Comment: Great! You could accept the the answer if you wish.